# Add minutes to Time Field in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I need to add minutes in my time field in lightning component.
When I simply try to add it, it's just concatenating them because time is in string type.

Is there an easy way to add minutes in the time field?

```
let programDataVar = component.get("v.ObjectName");
let fromTime = programDataVar.Start_Time__c;
let endtime = programDataVar.End_Time__c;

console.log(">>> Added time... "+fromTime + 30);
```

If my start time is **00:30:00.000** on adding 30 minutes it's becoming **00:30:00.00030**

I know I can truncate each time attribute and then add minutes to it. But I want to make it dynamic, without truncating any value and adding any minute or hour.

Answer (score 0):

The unit for adding or subtracting time values in milliseconds. For example,
Timefield1__c has the value "2:00pm":

Timefield1__c + 600000 is “2:10pm”
so 1min=60,000 milliseconds ,therefore for 30 min=30*60,000=1800000ms

Hope it helps!!